# Планшеты и ПК

Tags: android, пк

Всем привет, вот скажите сейчас уже переходят с Ноутбуков/Нетбуков на планшеты и пр. которые вообще маленькие, так вот они все на Android'e так вот скажите это что получается что большие компьютеры(ПК) вытесняют? Ведь те программисты которые будут писать под ПК для Windows, что с ними будет? Очень не хотелось бы уходить с уже родного C# на Android, чтобы работать на любимой работе. Или я что-то не правильно понял, разъясните пожалуйста.

Comment: > так вот они все на Android'e

Далеко не все! Еще популярные iOS, Windows 7. И прочие менее популярные...

Comment: Ну и по существу, планшет мне никак не заменяет ПК, даже на долю! Ибо ПК у меня очень серьезная махина!

Answer (score 3):

Вряд ли ПК уйдут с рынков. Есть ведь ещё и UltraBook, думаю будущее за ними.

Comment: Просто вон раньше все говорили "Ух ты у меня есть ПК, мне больше ничего не надо", а сейчас(ну по крейней мере у меня знакомые) говорят "ПК, да ну их, есть планшет где всё более удобное" Это я всё примерно описал.

Answer (score 2):

Рынок меняется. Рабочие станции остаются в офисе. Планшеты - дома. Телефоны - в дороге. Так как сейчас Android - самая популярная ОС для мобильных систем, и не видно причин, по которым это положение дел может измениться, а доля рынка мобильных систем растет, то и удельных вес в разработке софта под Android будет расти. Так что вполне возможно, что придется осваивать после C# - Java. Это обычное дело для нашей профессии.

Comment: Вот блин авторам не имется, зачем создали этот планшет!!! Нет бы сидели все на нетбуксах под Widnows и было бы счастье.

Answer (score 2):

Выбор есть и будет всегда. С появлением Windows 8 вы сможете свободно использовать свой любимый managed C#. Сможете писать код для компов и легко адаптировать его под планшеты и телефоны.